# Submit form Store Response

Tags: php, javascript, forms, iframe, asp-classic

I have a form the lies on a server I do not have control of.  Lets call it form1.  I know the POST requirements of form1.  I am creating my own form to submit data to that form1.  Lets call that one form2.  Form1 returns a ticket number, I need to store that ticket number into a department database, along with other information (that part I am ok with).  So I need form2(my form) to submit data to form1(ITs form) and store the response from form1 into our department database.

What is the easiest way to do this?  I have searched online for hours, and have come up empty. I went from javascript to iFrame to Ajax to jQuery.  And I am just lost now.

My server is a PHP server, theirs is a ASP server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a client-side operation, it is a server side operation. There is no need for "form2". You want to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for this. Something like this:

```
// Set up a connection to the target of form1 (this is the "action" attribute of form1)
$curl_connection = curl_init('http://hostname.com/form1.asp');

// Set up so options -- connection timout, store to string, follow redirects
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

// Set the post fields, this is just like a query string and contains the contents of form1 fields
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field1=value1&field2=value2");

// Run the query and capture the results
$data = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);

// At this point $data should contain the ticket number
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  It has to be a client-side operation.  The "form1" server will not accept any connections that do not negotiate NTLM authentication.  So I have to make it look like the user at the internet browser is submitting the form.  The above solution is an awesome solution, however I have tried it :(.  The server responds with an "unauthorized".  And I have tried sending a password in clear text, and it doesn't like that either.